# Shader programming - test if between two values

Tags: optimization, shader

Shaders allow `if(x>a && x<b)` but my understanding is logical tests are slow. Is this worth optimizing along the lines:

```
mid = (a+b)*.5;
half = (b-a)*.5;
if(abs(x - mid) < half){...}
```

It seems a lot more code but from the days of CPU ASM, such tricks were sometimes worth doing.

If `half` and `mid` can be calculated once on the CPU and passed in as shader parameters, then we replace: `if(x>a && x<b)` with: `if(abs(x - mid) < half)` - is *this* worth bothering with?

In my tests I see a little improvement pulling `half` and `mid` into pre-calculated shader params, but I've only one GPU to test on so I'm after a "in general" answer, and if there are cases it will be dramatically better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

The precalculating part of the shader params could be irrelevant (especially on directx), as the compiler is often smart enough to figure out the expression is constant.

Question is how abs is implemented. What's your target GPU? Mobile,mid,highend?